# How can I alleviate 'Run-Time Error 3078' after renaming queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Morning! I recently renamed a ton of queries I had in Access, went through the VBA and renamed every reference to those queries too. Now when I attempt to use a form that pulls & populates from those queries, I get a runtime Error 3078: Microsoft Office Access database engine is unable to find the input table or query ‘**old query name**’.

When I select debug it takes me to a line that reads:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qry_'NewQryName'_LineItems_TotalPerYear WHERE (EstimateID = " & EstimateID & " AND YearID >= " & StartYearID & " AND YearID <= " & EndYearID & ")"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

The new name is in the code but the error says it can't find the old name. Very confused, please help.

Comment: You need to change the Data Source of the form.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info? I'm looking into exactly what you mean

Comment: Have you tried to compact and repair?

Comment: Where is this code - what event? What is RecordSource of form? Just changing name in VBA will not change every reference to old name. Any references in query objects or textboxes will have to be edited. I used a third-party app called Rick Fisher's Find and Replace to accomplish.

Comment: Open your form in design view, the property sheet should be displayed on the right hand side. Make sure Form shows in the dropdown box. On the Data tab the first item is the Record Source. This should match the current name of your query.